# Existence of conformal mapping between two regions

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Let $\Omega$ be a simply connected nonempty open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ such that $0\notin \Omega$. Show that there is a holomorphic bijection $\phi:\Omega \to \Omega'$ where $\Omega' \subset \mathbb{D}$ is simply connected nonempty open set.

Notice: Do NOT use Riemann mapping theorem.

Of course this is trivial by Riemann mapping theorem, but how can I show the existence without using that theorem? I guess this has something to do with complex logarithm since $\Omega$ is simply connected and $0 \notin \Omega$. Does anyone have ideas?

Any hints or advices will help a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can proceed as follows:

- There exists a holomorphic logarithm on $\Omega$, i.e. a holomorphic function $L: \Omega \to \Bbb C$ such that $e^{L(z)} = z$ for all
  $z \in \Omega$.
- $h(z) = e^{\frac 12 L(z)}$ is a holomorphic square root on $\Omega$,
  i.e. $h(z)^2 = z$ for all
  $z \in \Omega$.
- Let $U = h(\Omega)$. Then $w \in U \Longrightarrow -w \not\in U$.
- Choose any disk $\overline{B_r(w_0)}\subset U$. Then $\overline{B_r(-w_0)} \cap U = \emptyset$, so that $\vert h(z) + w_0 \vert > r$ for all $z \in \Omega$.
- $\phi(z) = \dfrac{r}{h(z)+w_0}$ is injective and $\phi(\Omega) \subset \Bbb D$.

(This is essentially the first part of the proof of the Riemann mapping theorem in “Ahlfors, Lars V. Complex Analysis: An Introduction to the Theory of Analytic Functions of One Complex Variable”.)

Comment: Here $\Omega'$ may not be identical to $\phi(\Omega)$. $\Omega'$ is given prior to $\phi(\Omega)$.

Comment: Oh, it was a typo. I edited the comment.

Comment: @bellcircle: Are you sure that you interpret the task correctly? If  $\Omega'$ is *given* then it would be *equivalent* to the Riemann mapping theorem, i.e. you would be asking to *“prove the Riemann mapping theorem without using the Riemann mapping theorem.”*

Comment: I'm not sure. This question is from a qualifying exam of complex analysis, and the original question states that "Let $\Omega$ be a simply connected nonempty open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ such that $0\notin\Omega$. Without using the Riemann mapping theorem, show that there is a holomorphic bijection $\phi:\Omega\to\Omega'$ with $\Omega'\subset\mathbb{D}$"

Comment: @bellcircle: I am fairly sure that $\Omega'$ is not prescribed. – This is a standard part of the proof of the Riemann mapping theorem, to show that the (normal) family of injective functions from $\Omega$ into the unit disk is not empty. – Then ones shows that this family has an element for which $|f'(a)|$ is maximal and that this element maps *onto* the unit disk. That is what your other question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2846363/42969 is about.

Comment: @bellcircle: ... otherwise you could chose $\Omega' = \Bbb D$, and had a proof of the Riemann mapping theorem.